# closest point to set of surfaces

Tags: matlab, optimization, minimization

I have these surfaces defined by their position in space (x, y, z). Ideally, they should intersect but it is not always the case. However, there should be a point that has the shortest Ecludian distance from all the surfaces. I do not have analytical expressions for my surfaces. How would I find this point rather than going through all the possible candidates, which could be thousands?

Comment: First of all, you need to be more precise. What do you mean by "shortest Euclidean distance"? Do you mean minimum SUM of distances to the surfaces? Or minimum worst-case distance to those surfaces? Plus, how exactly are the surfaces defined?

Comment: Yes, minimum sum of distances. How exactly they are defined? They are set of points on a grid. Think Matlab's meshgrid in 3D. Or points within a region in 3D in x,y,z, forming a continious surface. If they were 2D, they would have defined a set of curves. And the question then would have been, what is the intersection points of the curves, or if they do not intersect, where is the point closest to them all. Or, a very simple case, just a set of lines. But then I could write the line equations and find the point. But not when I am dealing with surfaces in 3D.

Comment: would this question be different if you consider all these spaces as a single sparse space?

Answer (score 1):

In case you know the mathematical equations behind those surfaces, I'd recommend finding the closest point by formulating a least squares problem and solving analytically.

If you don't know anything about those surfaces, you should try either:

1. Exhaustive search - Slow, but when it is feasible, it always works.
2. Some kind of non-linear optimization method, like `fminsearch`. If those meshes have enough points, you can simply find the closest point. If not, you should do some kind of interpolation as well. If you have some starting point, supply it to the algorithm.